# IntelliJ not resolving Activator-Play build.sbt libraryDependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am using the latest **IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Community Edition**. After importing the Activator-Play project, IntelliJ is still showing the errors on imports. I have everything placed in `build.sbt` file.

[image]

But still the tooltip shows `Cannot resolve symbol '****'`.

[image]

This is an Activator project. I used `activator new` command to create the project with the `play-java` template and imported into IntelliJ. 
Anything that we can do with SBT configuration in IDEA. Can someone help me out?

Comment: did you use the "play-scala" template? Did you add additional dependencies, and did you refresh the project after adding them?

Comment: I used play-java. I refreshed the project. I am using Latest version of Intellji Community Edition

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the given information. Please provide a link to an example project that shows the issue. In general it is also helpful to not only provide screenshots but also the code that does not work.

Comment: Steps to reproduce  <br/>
1. Create a play-java project using activator <br>
2. Use Intellji 17.1 Community Edition <br>
3. Import the Project using SBT <br>
4. There you see errors. <br>
Let me know if you need project, I can share.

Comment: I tried those steps and it seems to work fine. Please do share a specific project where you see errors.

Comment: It's working there are no issues when I run the project. But IDEA  (Intellji) shows lot of errors.

Comment: Yes, but it also works fine for me in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating to **Intellji IDEA Ultimate Edition** solved the issue. Community Edition doesn't support the Play/ Activator applications.